# Align <ul> next to image, in middle

Tags: html, css

I have an `<img>` floated to the left and a `<ul>` next to it, hover the image is much bigger than the `<ul>` and therefore the page currently looks like [image: this]

My objective is to place the `<ul>` 'in the middle of the image, next to the image - this is an example of what I mean: [image: this]

Here's the code I'm currently using:

**HTML**

```
 <img src="logo.png" style="height: 250px; width: 250px; float: left;" />
    <ul>
    <li>Example</li>
    </ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
 background-image: url(ulbackground.png);
 list-style-type: none;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 height: 105px;
 width: 621px;
 vertical-align: middle;
 display: table-cell;
}

li {
 display : inline-block;
}
```

Comment: This may help: http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/ — I reference this one a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this work for you?

If you still need `float: left`, just add that to the `wrap` rule.

```css
.wrap {
  display: table;
}

.wrap img {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

ul {
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/350x50);
  list-style-type: none;
  background-position: left center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 105px;
  width: 621px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}

li {
  display : inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250" />
  <ul>
    <li>Example</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Brilliant, however one small problem has occurred. As you may of noticed in the code, the <ul> has a custom background. The <li> element is now how I wanted it, however the <ul> element hasn't moved. Here's an example of what I mean: http://prntscr.com/a34btg

Comment: @NOYOU454 I updated the answer and added a dummy image + `background-position: left center;` ... better now?